# Is it viable to do 1x100%5RM 3 times a week?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, strength-training, weight-gain, strength-gain

I begin each exercise of my workout with a set splitted into 3 sub-sets.
- 100% 5RM
- 30s rest pause
- 3 or 4 reps with the same weight
- 30s rest pause
- 4 or 5 reps with decreased weight denoted X

Then I do other sets, with X and decreased weights... but that's off topic.

This is done in each of my 3 workouts for each exercise in each week for each. So 3 times a week, per exercise. And even 6 times a week for my shoulders in isolation.

Is my first splitted set viable and efficient?
Aim: to train my nervous central system and my fibers recruitment. So my strength. And my endurance in strength. And my hypertrophy too.

I eat a lot of carbs, fats and proteins. I am gaining fat so I have reached my maintenance.

But at bench press I did not feel any pertinent enhancement.

Comment: Do you mean 5RM?

Comment: 100%5RM is the weight that allows to do 5RM. 50%5RM is the weight that allows to do 5RM divided by 2,so it is 100%10RM in other words.

Comment: Ok, you just wrote "5MR" instead of "5RM" in your question. :-)

Comment: `I am gaining fat so I have reached my maintenance.` What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: If you do 100% 5RM, and then after 30s you do another 4 reps with that weight, it was definitely not 100% 5RM.

Comment: Also, 50% 5RM is not the same as 100% 10RM, it does not work linearly like that.

Comment: @xdecdec Yes, it is. At the DC converging machine, I do 100%5RM at 35kg on each side. I calculated my 100%1RM and the calculator displayed 39kg. And indeed I can't even push once at 40kg.
So I do well 1x5@100%5RM 30s rest 1x3@100%5RM

Comment: No, it is not. Generally speaking, moving higher rep weight is a better indicator for muscle mass, while lower reps have a larger factor of skill, technique and neural adaptations. Estimated rep max calculators also get more inaccurate the higher reps you use for the estimation.

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean with `I am gaining fat so I have reached my maintenance.`?

Comment: @xdecdec I tell you I reach my nervous limit after 100%5RM, but I can do 3reps at this same weight after 30s of rest-pause, and that it was in adequation with the calculator. Why can't you believe it? Calculators are still good for 5reps and are frequently used at 5RM to calculate 1RM. Why do you  explain me some basis of workout (about ranges)? ---------- Well it means that I eat enough to be able to progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're looking for is an answer to the question "is my programming effective?". Programming effectively is a very important part of getting strong, so this is a good thing to be asking.

My hunch from looking at your program is **"no, there's not enough training volume and there's too much intensity".**

But... it's complex. **TLDR I would advise you to stop self programming and go pickup a well reviewed beginner program.**

There actually is no such thing as an "effective program", just an "effective program for you". Beginners have different responses to training than elite level athletes, and have massively different programming needs. You also need to be alert, write down everything and be able to detect when a program that was previously working stops working. This stuff isn't impossible, but it's easier to do with experience.

Incidentally, your slightly sloppy (sorry bro...) self-programming has been working great so far, because everything works at the start. Being a beginner lifter is fantastic, requires very little thought and the gainz come easy. What you're experiencing right now is a plateau in how far an ineffective program will take you. I guess you don't want to get stuck at the gym bro level forever, so it's time to start training smart.

Understanding how to program right is interesting field and one you can come to understand very well. But the best way to start is to "stand on the shoulders of giants" and take advantage of the people who have read all the [boring books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0982522754) and watched all the [long](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IEFJ_90vGE) [boring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdGP120e4B0) videos. In short you should look at set programs aimed at people at your level of training adaption. I would recommend [something like Barbell Medicine's beginner program](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/the-beginner-prescription/) (It's like starting strength but a bit less brutal). After you plateau with that, switch to something more intermediate (eg Texas Method, Greg Nuckol's Intermediate Programs, Barbell Medicine's 'The Bridge' etc). Before you know it you'll have [built experience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kbSfFFEvxw), learned the upsides and downsides to these programs, and will be in a position to make your own. But have patience for now.